# What's the difference between the DrawText() and DrawTextLayout() methods for Win2D?

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

Would like to know the difference between the `DrawingSession.DrawText()` and `DrawingSession.DrawTextLayout()` methods. Microsoft does oh-so-much to detail their developer tools.... I digress. -_-

When is it proper to use one over the other? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For more advanced features or drawing the same text repeatedly, use `DrawTextLayout`.  Otherwise `DrawText` works fine.

See [this overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to--draw-text) or the documentation for [DrawTextLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-drawtextlayout):

> When drawing the same text repeatedly, using the DrawTextLayout method
>   is more efficient than using the DrawText method because the text
>   doesn't need to be formatted and the layout processed with each call.